# Print only if field is not empty

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a text file that I want to pull host and IP info from only if the IP exists in column 4.  For example:

```
cat hostlist.txt
Server One 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
Server Two 255.255.255.255 
Server Three 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
```

In this case I would only want to see Server One and Three as Server Two has no data in the fourth column.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
awk '{if ($4) print $0;}' < hostlist.txt
```

does the trick. It's functionally equivalent to the earlier solution but is simpler since you only check for existence rather than matching a regex.

Comment: since `awk` commands are formed as `condition { actions }`, and since the default action is to print, this can be condensed to just `awk '$4' hostlist.txt` :)

Comment: This is true given the way the question is phrased. I gave the conditional form because it gives more flexibility (for example, if you didn't want to print the entire line)

Answer (score 5):

If you can live with lines where field 4 has value `0` not being printed, you can simplify to

```
$ awk '$4' hostlists.txt
Server One 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
Server Three 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
```

This is functionally equivalent to `{if ($4) print $0;}`, but reduced to just a pattern and using the default action of `print $0`.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'NF>=4 && $4~/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/' hostlist.txt
```

The output:

```
Server One 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
Server Three 255.255.255.255 123.123.123.123
```

---

`NF>=4` - ensures that a record has at least 4 fields

`$4~/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/` - ensures that the 4th field contains IPv4 address (in most simple form. Real IPv4 validation requires an additional conditions)